# Nodejs, PM2, and nginx deploying security?

Tags: node.js, security, nginx, production-environment, pm2

There are a few guides online that show how to get nodejs running on a server, but they tend to skip over a few details on security. This is a bit of a loaded question, and I'm not sure where to begin. I was wondering if someone could clarify the following details.

First, my setup:

- I have installed node locally with a non-sudo user because running node with admin is a bad idea:

  ```
  /home/appuser
      |--- nodejs/               # node install
              |--- bin/
              |--- include/
              |--- lib/
              |--- share/

      |--- app/
              |--- node_modules/
              |--- public/        # holds html templates, static files , uploaded files
              |--- core/          # holds main app js files
              |--- app.js         # Main Nodejs program
              |--- config.js      # Configuration that holds authentication details, other config stuff
              |--- package.json
  ```

  I can run the application using `PM2` by doing `pm2 start app.js`.

  My `nginx` configuration:

  ```
  server {
      listen 80;

      server_name mydomainname.com;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
  }
  ```

My concerns are:

**(1) APPLICATION** - Should the main `app/` live inside `/home/appuser`?

- Any danger in having my app files live inside my non-sudo user home? If so, where should my app files live?
- I'm wondering if `public/` should be in a different place and not live in the same folder as the application files. I wouldn't want the application source files to leak out, especially my `config.js` which holds some sensitive information like my database auth details and email auth details.

  If it should be moved, where `/public` live relative to `app/`?
- Right now permissions on `app/` are `chown -R appuser:appuser app/`, so that user owns all the files. Are there other permissions I should set on my application folder?

**(2) PM2** - Since I installed nodejs and its modules locally, how would I safely get `pm2` to restart my nodejs app after a server restart?

- My understanding is that `pm2-init.sh` will live in `/etc/init.d/`, and this happens automatically if I had installed `pm2` globally with sudo.

  How should I get `pm2` to restart my app safely using my non-sudo user?

**(3) NGINX**

- How can I safely serve `public/` through `nginx` if they are served like this:

  ```
  http://mydomainname.com/public
  ```
- My app handles routes and should throw `404` if a route is not found. But is it possible for someone to work around that and maliciously make my app or `nginx` browse other directories?

  ie, outside of app directory

  ```
  http://mydomainname.com/../../etc/path/to/secrets
  ```

  or, just locally in my app

  ```
  http://mydomainname.com/public/../../config.js
  ```

  Are there extra security precautions that can be set in `nginx` or nodejs to prevent this if this is possible?

Comment: This is way too many questions for an actual question on Stack Overflow, if you'd like ping me in that JavaScript chatroom and I'll answer them http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript

Comment: About the startup script `pm2 startup -u myUser` [see here](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#startup-script)

Answer (score 0):

1. The way I adopt is to have all the files be `node:node-developer`. And your start your app under `node` user. where node-developer is a group for developers. and set all your file permissions to `770`
2. Write a simple shell script that logs into `node` user and start pm2 as init scirpts
3. Solved by using proper permission settings. Nginx runs under `nginx` user. If the files are public, make it `nginx:nginx`. Even user could do `public/../../something`. Nginx would not have rights to access it.